# Tortoise SVN - Files shows as modified but parent folder shows as unmodified

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have installed tortoise svn 1.9.5 in windows 8.1, I am facing one problem in this.

Files shows as modified with [image] icon but parent folder shows as unmodified with [image] icon.

Why is this happaning?

Comment: Read the FAQ: https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlwrong

Comment: It says for cleanup. But problem is still occurring.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by enabling Status Cache to - Default mode.
By default - It'll be on Shell.

[image]